# Returning CosmosDB JSON data in a Node Function App

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have implemented a HTTP trigger function app. The application should return a json response of all the users in the database collection when I GET request on the /api/users route, but it returns an empty response (which it shouldn't).

The code is as:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


module.exports = async function(context, req) {    
    const auth = {
        user: process.env.CosmosDB_username,
        password: process.env.CosmosDB_password
    };

    const url = process.env.CosmosDB_url;
    MongoClient.connect(url, { auth: auth }, (err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        const database = connection.db('database');
        database.collection('User').find().toArray((err, users) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            users.forEach(user => {
                console.log(user);
            });

            context.res = {
                body: users
            };

            connection.close();
        });
    });
};
```

When I go the the /api/users route either on getpostman or google chrome browsers, there is no response returned, but in my visual studio terminal, I can see the list of users in json format being printed out via the console.log() method (since i am testing it locally).

I even tried debugging the application and have found out that context.res.body is populated by an array of length 10, which is equivalent to the JSON objects being printed our via console.log().

Comment: The function isn't returning anything, and there's no `await` inside it, something I would expect in an `async function`. I'm guessing `context` is sent back long before it is populated on the server.

Comment: +1 to @neklak's comment, remove the `async` and add `context.done();` after `connection.close();`. You're mixing promises and callbacks, which is generally not recommended for JavaScript (https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/04/06/nodejs-promises-callbacks/). Another note: instead of `console.log` try `context.log` to get logs in production that are tied to your function execution environment.

Comment: Should write this out as an answer Marie ( from Cosmos team)

Comment: Thanks @MarieHoeger it worked. Answer it below so I can mark it as verified and close this thread.